# Has the Raspberry Pi Zero enough power to act both as a Pihole and a print server?

Tags: pi-zero-w, server, pi-hole

My family has a vacation home were there is an old printer that does not have Wifi. The house also lacks an ad blocker so i thought: why not fixing both with a Raspberry Pi? I still have an unused Zero W here and wonder if that device has enough power to do both tasks.

I know it has enough power to do the PiHole but im not sure if it can do the other job too.

Comment: No harm in trying, literally, no harm will come to you or your $10 device if you actually tried and it failed ... though, I would guess that it would be fine, it's not like you'd be printing 24/7 while 100 devices are accessing the intergoogles

Comment: Well i rather would like to know if the print server would decrease the wifi performance ':)